Find the segment $x$ in the semicircle below
In the figure shown, if $PM = MQ = 4$, calculate $x$.
$O$ and $O'$ are centers.
(Answer:$x=4$)

I try:
$\triangle OQA: (OP+8)^2 = OA^2+AQ^2 =OA^2 +(AC+CQ)^2$
$\triangle OCB: AC^2 = AO.AB$
$\triangle OCB: (2R)^2 = OC^2+BC^2$= 4R^2$
$\triangle OPB:2R^2 = OP^2+BP^2=4R^2$
$ \therefore OP^2+BP^2 = OC^2+BC^2$

Just to make sure: Do we have $R\neq r$? In other words, $O'$ is not on the arc?

@Etemon Since the question doesn't mention anything, we must assume that they are different

Consider the circle through the four points $Q,P,A,B$. We have $OP.OQ=OA.OB$. Also, $OC^2=OA.OB$

Note that $BP$ is perpendicular to $OQ$ (inscribed in a semicircle) and consider the circle through the four points $Q,P,A,B$.
We have $OP.OQ=OA.OB$
We also have, in triangle $OCB$, $OC^2=OA.OB$
This implies $OC^2=OP.OQ$ which gives
$r^2-x^2=(r-4)(r+4)$ and therefore $x=4$


Comment: This construction may be a particular case:
$PO=2$
The radius of the circle $O'$ is equal to that of the circle $O$ which is equal to $6$.
KE is a perpendicular bisector of MC . Now if the circle centered at C with radius CD passes throgh E, this makes IE the radical axis of circles M and C and deuces that $CD=QM=4$.
Maybe this the only possible construction.
